# Jenkins - grant different permissions to different users

Tags: jenkins, permissions, continuous-integration, roles

I want to be able to distinguish users who are permitted to execute builds on `staging` env from users who are permitted to deploy on `prod`.

Is there some kind of roles mechanism in `Jenkins`? I could not find any reference to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [Role Strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) to do that.

In the Jenkins admin section, you can create project roles:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next, you can affect these roles to users or groups (if you are using a user directory like LDAP):

[image]

[image]

I hope it will help :)